# Webmatrix - Regularly run a SQL query

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

i have an SQL query (shown below) that i need to run on a regular basis:

```
db.execute("UPDATE property_info SET IsActive=false WHERE ExpiryDate > @0", CurrentDate);
```

This query is basically intended to check ALL properties, and to see whether or not they are past their expiration date. If they are, then it will automatically set the property to Inactive. Because "CurrentDate" is a rolling window, i want to re-run this query automatically, probably every day.

Is this something i should be using a stored procedure for?

Any suggestions on the best way to achieve this without any user interaction?

Comment: Sorry, just to add, i am using SQL server express (due to budget unfortunately), so SQL Agent jobs are out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to achieve this would be to add the line of code to `_PageStart.cshtml` in the root of your project. This will make it execute every time any page on the site is executed. That is probably massively overkill for something that, by the looks of it, only needs to be checked once a day or so. To alleviate this you could employ a simple `DateTime` stamp in the `Application` collection to make sure it only runs a maximum of once every day or so (or tune the interval as appropriate for your needs). This is in no way a solution for fully scheduled code execution, but it may well serve your purposes (and your budget).

Comment: Without the DateTime stamp in the Application collection, i think that might be a bit overkill :p but with it, it will definitely serve as a solution for the time being. I will eventually upgrade to SQL Standard, and then run this using the SQL Server Agent. I'll let you know how i get on with the Application collection, as that's completely new territory for me :)

Comment: It works in the same way as the `Session` collection except that values stored in it are shared across the entire server application instead of per user. As with the `Session` object, it is generally good advice to keep your use of it as minimal as possible.